# "You do not have permission to call showModalDialog"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

We first noticed this issue Friday, June 8. It could have been lurking for some time before that, as we don't use the add-on frequently. We first saw it running "Test as add-on..." from the project on script.google.com, regardless of version of code being tested. Then we had multiple users reproduce the issue from their own accounts, using the public addon downloaded from G Suite Marketplace. The public add-on dates back to May 2 and it was working fine when published.

Open any sheet in Google Drive, and get the Workforce Dimensions Admin add-on. Choose "Generate settings file" and get the error message "You do not have permission to call showModalDialog".

Is this a known issue affecting other add-ons as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [comment #65](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109859728#comment65) to [Critical: Google Docs Add ons show error "You do not have permission to call showSidebar"](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109859728)

> Hello,
>
> We have introduced a new scope -
> `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"`.  For most
> add-ons the new scope requirement should have been added to the add-on
> automatically.  In this case Apps Script did not detect that the
> add-on requires the scope because the reference to the top level bean
> "SpreadsheetApp" is in a different file than the function
> "showSidebar()".  In order to resolve similar issues, developers
> should ensure both top level bean and bean method are referenced in
> the same file or explicitly declare all scopes requirements in the
> manifest.  For more information on explicit scopes, please reference
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes.
>
> Thanks, Peter

---

Yes, this is a known issue as there are several recent issues on the Google Apps Script Issue Tracker like the following:

- [Critical: Google Docs Add ons show error "You do not have permission to call showSidebar"](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109859728)
- [Error "You do not have permission to call showSidebar" in onOpen and onEdit](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69238694)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is still not fixed by Google, even adding the `googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui` the scope did not change anything for me, but I found a different way :

All you have to do is manually creating the `onEdit` trigger in your Project's triggers, the scope will, therefore, be effective. It worked for me and the problem might be coming from the fact that you use a Simple Trigger and not an Installable one.

Comment: My code has the scope and installed triggers and the issue persists for me, unfortunately. The account that owns the trigger and the spreadsheets has no issue showing the dialog, but if an editor of the file does the action that's supposed to trigger the dialog, I receive an error notification.

Comment: @CalamitousCode you might see this same issue if your installable trigger has the same name of the simple trigger (e.g. if the `onEdit` function's name is `onEdit(e)`). If the name is the same, the simple trigger still gets called and it's a race to who gets called first. If that's the case, rename your function and redo the `onEdit` trigger for the new function name.

Answer (score 0):

My solution: After editing the manifest and adding the required scopes -> Delete the affected installed trigger and reinstall it. After that, it worked as expected.

Remember: Simple Triggers has limited access to resources.