# How to get Google sheet Apps Script to run onOpen function for all users with edit permissions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a popup box that shows directions but it only shows when i open the sheet. I want it to run when any user that has access to it opens it. Just to clarify, the other users are editors.

My toast box does show up for the other users but the html app does not

Here is my script:

```
    function onOpen() {
      var message = "Let's have a productive day!";
      var title = 'Welcome Back Greeter';+
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(message, title, 10);


      var htmlApp = HtmlService
         .createHtmlOutput('<p>Make sure you mark the following each time a plate is taken or returned: </p>----Salesperson Name </p>----Time Out </p>----Time In </p>----and if it is Pupped! </p>Do not let Salespeople take plates themselves! </p>As Greeters we are responsible for tracking these plates. This sheet is going to be reviewed with Bob each night with a list of which plates are out for the night as well as a list of the plates that are currently in their folders for the next day. </p> Sincerely, The Plate Fairy</p>')
         .setTitle('!!!!!  ATTENTION GREETER  !!!!!')
         .setWidth(350)
         .setHeight(400);

      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(htmlApp);
    }
```

Comment: Add the execution transcript.

Comment: There is a `+` after a `;` on the third line (`var title = 'Welcome Back Greeter';+`). Maybe that is causing the problem.

Comment: I would opt for either **run code from an image click** or **create a menu option**. Both of those will work just fine, and won't require people to authorize the script before it can run. If they don't authorize it, it won't run for them. Check console logs on Stackdriver after they view the sheet to verify for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The user would have to give your script permission to open a dialog box. So you would need to get them to create an [installable onOpen trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) which they would authorise and on subsequent opens would display your dialog.

There is no way you can force them to do this, you can only offer them the option in something like a custom menu option.

Answer (score 0):

Simple triggers are triggered only when the document, in this case a spreadsheet, is opened by the owner or an editor. By the other hand simple triggers have several restrictions, like they can't open dialogs, sidebars among other things.

For details see [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)

It's worth to note that currently there are some open issues that could be related with this thread. I already mentioned them on my answer to ["You do not have permission to call showModalDialog"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50823019/1595451)

Comment: The other users are Editors

Comment: @JonathanRupell please edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: I doubt simple triggers have the permission to show a sidebar or modal dialog without user interaction