# Use installable onedit trigger to call showModalDialog from a shared google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a question about calling showModalDialog from a shared google sheet.

Here is a demo for my question --

GS:

```
function createTrigger()
{
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('testtrigger')
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
  .onEdit()
  .create();
}

function testtrigger(event)
{
 var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var actRng = sheet1.getActiveRange();
 var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
 var editRow = actRng.getRow();
 var cell1 = sheet1.getRange(2, 2);
 var cell2 = sheet1.getRange(2, 3);

 if (editColumn == 1 && editRow == 2 ) //when updating the right cell
 {
  cell1.setValue("changed");
  showDialog();
  cell2.setValue("changed");
 }
}

function showDialog()
{
  var uiDialog = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('myHtml');
  return SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(uiDialog,"title");
}
```

myHtml.html:

```
<select>
 <option value="Test1">test1</option>
 <option value="Test2" selected="selected">test2</option>
 <option value="Test3">test3</option>
</select>
<hr/>
```

It works perfectly with my own account (both cell1 and cell2 have "changed"). However, I shared this document to a different account. Then the shared account seems have a problem with calling "showDialog();" (besides, only cell1 has "changed"). 
I guess it is an issue about authorization. Can someone tell me how to solve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: View >Executions.  Quote the error in your post. I don't think this is possible- it was disabled a while back for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks TheMaster: That's the strangest thing, The function status only has "Completed". No "Failed" record.. Can anyone reproduce the problem? Or just me..

Comment: Another interesting thing spotted: when debugging in the shared google sheet, everything works fine. I am so confused and desperately for help

Comment: Solution = your user must run `createTrigger`. Why? OK, be kind, I "think" I understand this ;). Though "you" created an Installable trigger and authorised the script, this does not extend to others (refer [“You do not have permission to call showModalDialog”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50823019/) and links-this is Google's _Intended Behavior_). When your user opens the spreadsheet and script editor, and looks at the Installable Triggers - it is blank. Your user must install their own Installable Trigger so that your user  can explicitly give permission for `showModalDialog`.

Comment: Thanks Tedinoz: My bad, because the cell1 has changed at the first place, I thought the installable trigger is fully functional.. May I ask a further question -- If I want avoid any script-end operation on the user's side(including manually insert an installable trigger), does publish as an add-on can work?

Comment: Good question - I don't know. Shouldn't be too hard to try it out. BTW, when replying to specific people, put the ampersand (@) at the start of their name - it will initiate autocomplete for spelling names and, more importantly, it will send them a notification of your comment.

Comment: @PeiranQuan Worth reading the documentation on [Add-on authorisation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/addon-authorization).

Comment: @Tedinoz Thx for your help! The installable trigger is not available in the "test as add-on" mode. I will try to deploy it on the market. Best,Peiran

Comment: @PeiranQuan Since they shut down Chrome MarketPlace, there have been a few teething problems raised in SO questions about how to update "private" add-ons, etc. The last thing that you want is to have to spend $95 to be regarded as a developer, AND then have your private add-on hanging out to dry along with all the commercial products. I'm not even sure that the documentation has been changed yet to reflect how one would "create" a private add-on. Might be worth playing a waiting game if you can afford the time.