# Google Apps script does not close form and if it does, it does not get the value back upon submission

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I was having execution errors `Exception: You do not have permission to call Ui.showModalDialog. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui`

So added oauthScopes in my appsscript.json:

```
"oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
]
```

And created an installable trigger "sheetUpdate" as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50823019/you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-showmodaldialog)

[image]

I have an "Actions" column in my spreadsheet; each cell under "Actions" column has a dropdown. It has a "Set Dependency" option. Upon selecting, it gets the current active row's Task ID (e.g. TSK-0002).

I am able to dynamically set the display content of the `<label>`.
[image]

Issue 1: If I don't place `closePrompt()` inside the Submit `<button>`. Clicking Submit, doesn't do anything. The custom dialog box does not close.

In the Dependencies dialog box, I am trying to get the label, selected dropdown option and inputted text upon submission.

Issue 2: With `closePrompt()` inside the Submit `<button>`. As per the execution logs, the Loggers inside the `case "Set Dependency":` are empty while the Loggers inside `setDependency(elementsObj)` are not executing.

[image]

Code.gs

```
...
let dependencyDlgObj = {
label: "",
dropdownChoice: "",
textInput: ""
};
...

function sheetUpdate(e) { 
...
getheaders();
...
case "Set Dependency":
    createDependencyPrompt(editedRange)          
    Logger.log("Label value: " + dependencyDlgObj.label);
    Logger.log("Dropdown value: " + dependencyDlgObj.dropdownChoice);
    Logger.log("Text input value: " + dependencyDlgObj.textInput);
    break;
...
}

function createDependencyPrompt(editedRange) {
//Open a dialog
  var htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Dependencies')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(480)
      .setHeight(300);

  activeTask = sheet.getRange(editedRange.getRow(), headersObj.Task_ID).getDisplayValue();
  console.log("activeTask:" + activeTask);
  htmlDlg.append('<script>window.onload = function() { document.getElementById("activeTaskLabel").textContent = "' + activeTask + '"; }</script>');

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(htmlDlg, 'Dependencies');
}

function setDependency(elementsObj) {
  // Use the retrieved values as needed
  dependencyDlgObj.label = elementsObj.label;
  dependencyDlgObj.dropdownChoice = elementsObj.dropdownChoice
  dependencyDlgObj.textInput = elementsObj.textInput;

  Logger.log("Label value: " + dependencyDlgObj.label);
  Logger.log("Dropdown value: " + dependencyDlgObj.dropdownChoice);
  Logger.log("Text input value: " + dependencyDlgObj.textInput);
}

function getHeaders() {
  headersDisplayValues.forEach((headerValues, headerColumnIndex) => {
    headerValues.forEach((header, columnNumber) => {                              
      trimmedHeader = header.split(" ").join("_");      
      headersObj[trimmedHeader] = columnNumber + 1;
    });
  });

  console.log(headersObj);  
}
```

Dependencies.html

```
...
<body>
    ...
      <div class="btn-text-right">
        <button type="button" onclick="closePrompt()" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="submitDependency(); closePrompt()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    ...
    <script>
      /* Upon clicking Cancel button */
      window.closePrompt = function() {
        google.script.host.close();
      };
    </script>
    <script>
      /* Upon clicking Submit button */
      function submitDependency() {
        var elementsObj = {
          label: "",
          dropdownChoice: "",
          textInput: ""
        };
        elementsObj.label = document.querySelector(".lbl-task").innerText;
        elementsObj.dropdownChoice = document.querySelector("select[name='Dependencies']").value;
        elementsObj.textInput = document.querySelector("input[name='taskright']").value;

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closePrompt).setDependency(elementsObj);
      }

      function closePrompt() {
        google.script.host.close();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
...
```

I am not sure where to start from here.

Comment: Could you share a sample spreadsheet or the full code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: When I was making a copy of the gsheet to share here, it needed to allow permission for Apps Scripts. And upon testing everything worked for the copy. I then removed and re-allowed permission on the original gsheet and everything works now.